# How to remove minitoc from Appendix?

Tags: minitoc

I'm writing my thesis and using `minitoc` to get a contents for each chapter. However I don't want this for the appendix, is there any way of removing it for this part of the document?

example:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,12pt,a4paper ,twoside ]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\null \vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries \abstractname \end{center}}%
{\vfill\null}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[]{nomencl}
\makeglossary

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\bfseries}
{\titlerule[4pt]\vspace{2pt}\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\LARGE        \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\LARGE\MakeUppercase{#1}}
[\normalsize\normalfont\vspace*{2pc}%
\hbox{\large\bfseries\contentsname}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule\vspace{3pt}
\startcontents
\printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\bfseries}
{}
{1pc}
{\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{1pc}\LARGE\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\usepackage{minitoc}    
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{xr}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\tableofcontents
\dominitoc
\listoffigures

\listoftables
\mainmatter
\chapter{chapter1}
\chapter{chapter2}
\appendix
\chapter{appendix} 
Here is appendix
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post a minimally compilable (!!!) example that has this issue -- your description is not sufficient to give any clue because we have no information what you have written in your document such that the `minitoc` appears at all

Comment: sorry, I've updated the question now

Comment: Yes, but it is far from minimal and has `scrbook`, `minitoc` and `titlesec` combined. That's an very unhealthy combination, as well as with `fancyhdr` ...

Comment: Ok sorry I'm fairly new to tex and wasn't sure how much to include to get the same influence. Is there a reason not to combine them? My pdf compiles fine of my whole thesis it is just that I don't want the minitoc for the appendix.